# Python aioodbc pyodbc.ProgrammingError: The cursor's connection has been closed

Tags: python, database, pyodbc

I have DB connector class based on aioodbc (wrapper of pyodbc) python lib (superclass almost the same, but to connect to PostreSQL database).
My service uses instance of this class to interact with MS SQL database.
If service interacts with database often, everything is okay, but if it does not have any interact during about 10 seconds (very short period), i have an error:
`The cursor's connection has been closed.`

I use connection pool there.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this issue?
From database side everything looks fine.

```
class MSDBClient(DBClient):
    def __init__(self, settings: Dict[str, Dict[str, Union[str, Dict]]], *,
                 loop: Optional[asyncio.AbstractEventLoop] = None,
                 pool_settings: Optional[Dict] = None):
        super().__init__(settings, loop=loop, pool_settings=pool_settings)

    async def setup(self):
        async with self._lock:
            for try_num in range(self.db_pool_tries):
                try:
                    self.db_pool = await aioodbc.create_pool(loop=self._loop, **self._settings)

                    self.db_select_result = await self.select('select top 1 id from dbo.risk_rule_type;', [])
                    if self.db_select_result:
                        logger.info('MS SQL Connection Established {uid}@{server}:{port}/{database}'.format(
                            **self._login_data))
                    else:
                        raise DBNoDataError(f'Select resulted as {self.db_select_result}')
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.error(f'Initial MS db pool error: {e}, sleep for {self.db_pool_timeout_seconds} second[s]')
                    await asyncio.sleep(self.db_pool_timeout_seconds)
                finally:
                    if self.db_pool and self.db_select_result:
                        break
                    if try_num == self.db_pool_tries - 1:
                        raise DBLoginTimeoutError(f'All {self.db_pool_tries} tries exceeded')

    async def close(self):
        async with self._lock:
            try:
                self.db_pool.close()
                await self.db_pool.wait_closed()
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f'MS db pool error: {e}')

    async def select(self, query: str, values: List) -> List[asyncpg.Record]:
        values = values or ()
        return await self._select(query=query, values=values)

    async def first(self, query: str, values: List) -> Optional[asyncpg.Record]:
        values = values or ()
        return await self._first(query=query, values=values)

    async def _select(self, query: str, values: List):
        try:
            async with self.db_pool.acquire() as conn:
                async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                    await cur.execute(query, *values)
                    return await cur.fetchall()
        except Exception as e:
            # TODO RAISE CUSTOM EXCEPTION
            logger.error(f'{e}:{query}')
            return {}

    async def _first(self, query: str, values: List):
        try:
            async with self.db_pool.acquire() as conn:
                async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                    await cur.execute(query, *values)
                    return await cur.fetchone()
        except Exception as e:
            # TODO RAISE CUSTOM EXCEPTION
            logger.error(f'{e}:{query}')
            return {}

    async def _execute(self, query: str, values: List):
        try:
            async with self.db_pool.acquire() as conn:
                async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                    await cur.execute(query, *values)
                    await conn.commit()

        except pyodbc.Error as e:
            logger.error(f'_execute pyodbc error: {e}')
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f'_execute error: {e}')

    async def insert(self, query: str, values: List):
        return await self._execute(query=query, values=values)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have deepen into aioodbc lib and find kinda solution.

Connection is closing independently in about few seconds (in connection properties `closed=True`) in my case.

I'm not sure if it's caused by database configuration or library issues.

**Solution**

pass `pool_recycle` parameter greater then -1 to `aioodbc.create_pool()`

when it is passed, connection usage time is checking before query and if it is greater than passed value, connection closes and if number of connections in pool less than minimum, the new connection is creating and is using to query database

see `_fill_free_pool` in **aioodbc/pool.py**

Note. Connection is renewing almost every query, which takes sensible amount of time